# How to patch fiber connection from secured to unsecured ports

Tags: cabling, fiber

I need to patch a fiber connection from a red secured (keyed) wall port to an unsecured (not-keyed) media converter. It is LC to LC Multimode Duplex. Who sells a secured to unsecured patch cable? Will I have to make this type of cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any "standardized" secure fiber connectors.  All the ones I am aware of are vendor proprietary.

As such, I would venture to say that you would have to check with the vendor of your secured connectors to see if they have such a product.  Of the ones I have seen, they either have such a cable or they have an "insert" that will secure the cable to the device as well.  If they didn't, their solution wouldn't be very useful as devices will come with standard connectors and incompatible with their solution.

If they don't have a solution for you (highly unlikely), you have three options.  Contact the vendor to see if they will make it.  Contact a third party cable manafacturer to see if they will make it.  Or, as you suggested, you will need to make it yourself.